# how to pass call value from callback function in tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, callback

I write this code, and i want to use value of

```
class saveselectvalue():
    def docallback(self , *args):
    value = combo.get()
    return value

root=tk.Tk()

root.title('Testing Tkinter Combobox With Sqllite')
root.geometry('500x600+150+80')

frame1 =tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=75, background="blue")
frame1.pack_propagate(False)
frame1.pack()

frame2 =tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=90, background="blue")
frame2.pack_propagate(False)
frame2.place(x=0 , y=77)

frame3 =tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=180, background="white")
frame3.pack_propagate(False)
frame3.place(x=0 , y=170)

combo=ttk.Combobox(frame1,width=15 , height=10 )
combo.place(x=300 , y=8)
df=sqltablename()
combo['values']=df.to_string(header=None , index=False)
valueselected=combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", saveselectvalue.docallback)
...
...
tree=ttk.Treeview(frame3)
tree.place(x=10 , y =0)
root.mainloop()
```

i want to choose data slected in combobox and use it to query from sqlite database as code below

```
con=sqlite3.connect('foo.db')
c = con.cursor()
d=combobbox selected value
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM  {};".format(d),con)
```

could any one help me to do this?
best regards

Comment: Why don't you just directly call `combo.get()` in the query task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need store this value, one way to do it, is creating an attribute in your class `SaveSelectValue`:

```
class SaveSelectValue():
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = None
```

Then your callback have to save the value:

```
def docallback(self , *args):
  value = combo.get()
  self.value = value
```

To bind the callback, first create an instance of your class and then use it to bind:

```
instanceSaveSelectValue = SaveSelectValue()
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", instanceSaveSelectValue.docallback)
```

Now you can use the attribute as you like:

```
print(instanceSaveSelectValue.value)
```

Comment: thanks a lot , when i want to use SaveSelectValue.docallback() it shows TypeError: docallback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' . could you answer what am i suppose to do?

Comment: You can't call SaveSelectValue directly, because calling like this you are trying to use a class method, you should first instantiate a new object, something like: 

instanceSaveSelectValue = SaveSelectValue()

and then you can use instanceSaveSelectValue.docallback()

Comment: If you have problems, consider search about Object Oriented Programming, all I talk  relationed to it, but feel free to ask, I will answer when I can. And if the answer has worked for you, then consider marking it as answer.